# How to create a KTable from an Object received through StreamListener?

Tags: java, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream

I want to create a KTable (in the future will be a GlobalKTable) to keep track of the entries that are going through my Kafka brokers using Spring Cloud Streams.

The code I have right now works as it should on the listener perspective, as it receives the data passed through Kafka and extracts the two Ids I need to create my registry.

The goal in the end (in a nutshell) is to create a place in the system so we can check if the data is being processed for that combination (the userId and the appId)

```java
// Peek on myBindings interface
public interface myBindings {

    String INPUT = "input";

    String OUTPUT = "output";

    @Input(INPUT)
    MessageChannel input();

    @Output(OUTPUT)
    MessageChannel output();

}

//Peek on the service

    @StreamListener(target = myBindings.INPUT)
    public void listenforMessage(@Payload String jsonAsString) throws IOException {
        ObjectNode node = new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonAsString, ObjectNode.class);
        KeyValue kvPair = new KeyValue<>(node.get(Info.USER_ID_KEY), node.get(Info.APP_ID_KEY));

        // Here comes the question...
    }
```

After inspecting (or printing) the pair, we see the data is correct. Then the question would be :

*How to build a KTable out of it, since I'm not using KStreams and my input object is different?*

All the examples I find online uses a KStream/KTables as entry point / parameter of the method, but there is no example around on something either using other types of entry.

New to Kafka / Spring Cloud Streams. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You do need a `KStream`. Actually, you can declare a separate binding of type `kstream` that creates the ktable directly from the topic. You can even materialize it into a key value store for lookup by configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model of Kafka Streams (and the one that is used in Spring Cloud Stream binder for this) is that you need to receive records from a Kafka topic and consume that as `KStream`, `KTable` or `GlobalKTable`. Currently, there is no inter-operability between the regular Kafka binder (using vanilla Kafka producer/consumer) and the Kafka Streams binder as the target types for the two binders are entirely different. You can use two separate `StreamListener` methods where one is a vanilla Kafka consumer (using the Kafka binder) and the other one is a Kafka Streams binder based consumer. As to your specific use case that you are describing, I think you can handle that as a normal Kafka Streams application.

```
// Peek on myBindings interface
public interface MyBindings {

    @Input("input)
    KStream<?,? input();

}
```

```
@StreamListener
public void listenforMessage(@Input("input") KStream<?, String> input) throws IOException {
       input.... //operations on input KStream here. 

    }
```

You can materialize the data into a `KTable` using the functional operations available on `KStream`.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Now I get an error as follows.
`Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No factory found for binding target type: org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KStream among registered factories: channelFactory,messageSourceFactory`
Wondering if I'm missing a bean/config, as my application works pretty much with those MessageChannel input.

Comment: Is there a small standalone app where we can reproduce the issue? preferably on github.

Comment: Sorry for taking my time on this - was creating an entry in github when I got the issue above sorted. The error above was caused by the library version, was incompatible with other libraries I was using.
Using 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams' with version: '2.2.0.RELEASE' (instead of 2.0.0) solved it. 

Marking the answer as correct. Thanks.